# Best way to implement google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I found two way to implement google maps.

**The First One**

```
<script src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

**The Second One**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=....key"></script>
```

***my questions :-***

**1-** What is difference between them?

**2-** Can I download (save) a part of google maps (my country map or city) to my localhost?

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.

Comment: Hey there Alarees, although you've omitted the API key in a recent edit, this API key is still accessible by looking at this question's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34541779/revisions) page. I strongly suggest that you should revoke the API key as suggested by @SamuelLiew.

Comment: hi all, the api key is not mine, i get it from one of old tutorials, so i don't have the access for it

Answer (score 0):

For your second question

By Broswer  Google maps can only be executed using internet. Eventually local copy are actually not allowed and above all does not work. Google Maps can used only as a service and not as a local library.
For Mobile you can access (and also edit) your maps locally [eg see this](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/2713925?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, you no longer need to define the `type` attribute for JS includes, so this format works:

```
<script src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Additionally, you are referencing the v3 of the Google Maps API with the above URL - [see here in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

Answer (score 0):

First question: This was answered by @staypuftman.

Second question: You may save a local copy of a part of google maps using [Google Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) which will return a value as an image file.